# mysql distinct value for count

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I am all over the place here. The MySql query below works for me except for two issues.

1) I want to make sure that only one result per category is displayed (I have 5 categories), I tried using DISTINCT but have clearly misunderstood that one.

2) I want to be able to return the howmany value outside the sql query:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT category_id, video_id, date_added, COUNT(video_id) AS howmany
FROM votes 
WHERE date_added BETWEEN SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND SYSDATE()
GROUP BY video_id 
ORDER BY howmany DESC, video_id
LIMIT 5";
```

my votes table looks like this:

```
id | video_id | category_id | date_added
```

EDIT:
Expected output -

video_id 2 category_id 4 number of votes 500

video_id 5 category_id 1 number of votes 377

video_id 88 category_id 3 number of votes 25

video_id 45 category_id 5 number of votes 23

video_id 9 category_id 2 number of votes 2

The highest voted video in each category over the last 7 days is displayed.

Comment: `DISTINCT` only removes duplicates from visibility - duplicates meaning the entire row of values is duplicated.  If only one column value is different, it's not considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you'd want to `GROUP BY category_id` instead, or even `GROUP BY category_id, video_id` if you want to break the results down further.

Comment: I agree, but does this not affect the value of howmany, will it not count based on all the videos in that category though?

Comment: If you group only by category_id, then yes. You'd get the total number of video votes for each category. If you group by both fields, then you'd get each individual video_id in each individual category.

Answer (score 2):

If you want only 1 result per category, you have to group by category. But since there could be multiple video_id's per category, you would end up getting a random one from within the category unless you use GROUP_CONCAT.

If you just want to get a distinct count of a column value, put the DISTINCT keyword inside the count function:

```
COUNT( DISTINCT video_id )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT category_id, video_id, date_added, COUNT(video_id) AS howmany
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
GROUP BY category_id, video_id, date_added, COUNT(video_id)
```

You said "I want to make sure that only one result per category is displayed", so you probably want something like this:

```
SELECT category_id, video_id, date_added, COUNT(video_id) AS howmany
FROM votes 
WHERE date_added BETWEEN SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND SYSDATE()
GROUP BY category_id 
ORDER BY howmany DESC, video_id
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have the analytic functionality you'd use for situations like these - use:

```
SELECT x.video_id,
       x.category_id,
       x.howmany
  FROM (SELECT t.video_id,
               t.category_id,
               COUNT(*) AS howmany,
               CASE 
                 WHEN @category = t.category_id THEN @rownum 
                 ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1 
               END AS rank,
               @category := t.category_id
          FROM VOTES t
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @category := -1) r
         WHERE t.date_added BETWEEN SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND SYSDATE()
      GROUP BY t.video_id, t.category_id
     ORDER BY t.category_id, howmany DESC) x
 WHERE x.rank = 1
ORDER BY x.howmany DESC
   LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Wow - and I don't have the analytic functionality to cope with situations like that either. Very nice but not quite working I'm afraid. And not throwing up any errors.
Thanks, though

Comment: @kalpaitch: No errors, but it's not returning the data you expect?

Comment: The page will stop loading, that is all. Not returning any data seemingly.

Comment: @kalpaitch: Page, as in PHP?  What about running the query from a prompt - either command line, phpmyadmin, MySQL Administrator/etc?

Comment: my mistake - the VOTES was claiming it was not a valid table so I decapitalized it, although, it only shows a single result now.

Comment: @kalpaitch: Run the main query - the one inside the brackets starting at the FROM and ending at the "x".  I'm thinking you don't have the data you think you do, based on the date filtration...